# arranging the list items to some ordered graphically

Tags: css

I am working on a simple pivot data from a table and trying to display the data in a horizontal list. I want to make the design as responsive to show also in mobile. Below is my simple css code

```css
.menu{
  width:700px; margin:0 auto;            
}
.menu li{
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.menu .fa {
  display: block;

}
.selected {
  color: green;
}
.menu li:hover{
  color: green;
}
  .list-heading {
  font-weight: normal;      
}
```

```html
<h3 class="list-heading">WeekName</h3>
<h3 class="list-heading">DayName</h3>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 5</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 4</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 3</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 2</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 1</span></li>    
</ul>
```

I want to display the data like this Image:

[image: Target display image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this css

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding:0px;
}
.menu li{
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30vw;
    height: 30vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 6px auto;
}
.menu li i{
  font-size:24px;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Html Goes here ....

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Where i can show week name and day name in some graphical way to display more attractive

Comment: can you please share the complete css and html code as shown in image

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to accomplish this. Personally I'd probably use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) but if you want to stick with an unordered list element you can just set the `li` children to `display: inline-block` and allow the DOM flow to do what it's supposed to do like shown below;

Side NOTE: the `<!-- -->` between the `li` elements is one way to negate the spacing that an `inline-block` element has by default without needing to add negative margins etc.

Hope this helps, cheers.

```css
.menu{
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
.menu li{ 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  padding: .5em;
}

.menu .fa {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: .5em 0;
}

.selected {
  color: green;
}

.menu li:hover{
  color: green;
}
.list-heading {
  font-weight: normal;      
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3 class="list-heading">WeekName</h3>
<h3 class="list-heading">DayName</h3>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li><!--
    --><li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x"></i><span>Meal 5</span></li><!--
    --><li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x"></i><span>Meal 4</span></li><!--
    --><li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x"></i><span>Meal 3</span></li><!--
    --><li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x"></i><span>Meal 2</span></li><!--
    --><li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x"></i><span>Meal 1</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a CSS media query. You'll need to define the width desired for when they change the stack order. I've set it to 480px. See my fiddle example below.

```
.menu{
      width:700px; margin:0 auto;            
    }
    .menu li{
      display: inline;
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 2em;
      padding: 0;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .menu .fa {
      display: block;

    }
    .selected {
      color: green;
    }
    .menu li:hover{
      color: green;
    }
      .list-heading {
      font-weight: normal;      
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     .menu li {
       margin: 0;
       width: 30%;
     }
   }
<h3 class="list-heading">WeekName</h3>
<h3 class="list-heading">DayName</h3>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 5</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 4</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 3</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 2</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-glass fa-1x" aria-hidden="false"></i><span>Meal 1</span></li>    
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbc59e38/

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex to layout easier. It all depends on your needs and html structure so sometimes you need to use with media queries. But try with flex first

```
.menu{
  max-width:700px; margin:0 auto;            
}
.menu li{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.menu .fa {
  display: block;

}
.selected {
  color: green;
}
.menu li:hover{
  color: green;
}
.list-heading {
  font-weight: normal;      
}
```